# How to merge multiple multidimensional arrays into one

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have several multidimensional arrays generated from loops. For example, I declare a variable n as number of points. If a user enters n as 4, 4 arrays would be generated based on For Next loop:

```
For i=1 to n
    Dim subA(1,5) As Double
    subA(0, 0) = 1
    subA(0, 1) = 9
    ...
Next
```

Now, I want to merge each subA array of each point i generated from the looping process into one single multidimensional array A.

How do I do this please?

Comment: You seem to be expecting a magic answer where none exists.  If you want a new array then you create a new array.  If you want to traverse a 2D array then you use two nested `For` lops that's really all you need to know.

Comment: Are you saying it's not possible to merge arrays?

Comment: No, I'm saying that there is no magical `Merge` method that will do it for you.  You do it exactly as you would expect you would have to do it manually.

Comment: You already know how to declare a multidimensional (2D array). Declare a 3D array instead outside the loop and be done with it.